# C# .NET How to create array with a title, like DataRow?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, user-interface

I have a bunch of UI Control, created dynamically, and I want to access a specific control.

For now, I have a array which contain these controls, but now I can only use `myControlArray[i]`, I want to make a array with a tag, like `myControlArray["nameText"]`, just like `DataRow`.

How to create such array? or is there any alternative to program that?

Comment: `IDictionary<string, Control>`

Comment: _array with a title_ what a nice description :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your controls have distinct names, then go for a `Dictionary<string, Control>`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Control>();
dict.Add("yourName", youControl);

var control = dict["yourName"];
```

If your names are not guaranteed to be unique, then you can go for a `Dictionary<string, IList<Control>>` and have multiple controls under one name:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IList<Control>>();
dict.Add("yourName", new List<Control> {yourControl});

dict["yourName"].Add(anotherControl);

var controls = dict["yourName"];
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that the Dictionary collection type takes two different generic types `TKey` and `TValue`. So the key value doesn't explicitly have to be a string. It can be any other type (e.g. enum, string, int, another dictionary).

Comment: Thanks, I never used Dictionary before, and I'm doing my third big project with c#. I'm going to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Are you wanting to use a Dictionary?

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictionary.Add("key", "");
dictionary["key"] = "value";
```